# Receiving memory warning in ViewController ("Page swipe Style ScrollView")

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have a project where there are two views, in the first view i have a uitableview displayed. And on selecting any of the row cell the other view is opened.

First view have 10 cells and each cell when selected opens other view which consist like maximum 21 views and minimum 1 view within.

Each view in the second view consist of image array tableview and many subviews in tableview (also the image array is displayed within a scrollview with multiple image view)

Now the problem is I am not able to release my memory allocation which is not known to me because according to my code everything which is allocated is release. I have also tried instrumental but that doesn't work.

Previously when I visit only one view it crashed the application so for that I decrease the resolution of images and now it navigates for almost 9 app when no other app is open else it work for 6 view. Now I can't even reduce more resolution of images because that is already now of lower quality. So how could I reduce this memory allocation which is not at all supporting my app and nor even releasing the memory which is occupied.

Make sure you don't reply with suggestion like instrumental leak because that isn't helpful. I need to know how to release the unused memory.

[image]

You can see that there are three views in a single view and that is a scrollbar so as you navigate by scrolling more views would be displayed and there is image on the top which is also a scrollbar. Apart from this there is a tableview displaying details. But when I create this view I am facing problem of memory, so for that I am releasing everything from this view, even I tried to remove the whole view while navigating back. For this I have used "PagedFlowView" example

https://github.com/kejinlu/PagedFlowView

The above link is for pagedflowview example and the below link is for my code reference class which I have implemented please check my class and let me know where could I improve it.

http://www.4shared.com/file/rHmRDr2E/SwipeExerciseViewController.html

Comment: It would be nice of you to accept a correct answer to your question by clicking the gray checkmark next to it.

Comment: Why should i accept the answer if those were of no use to me. I found the answer by myself.

Comment: You can always submit an answer even if it is a question posted by you only, if you found out the solution and mark that as the correct answer. That way others who face the same problem will know the solution for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently had problems with the UITableView and in my case it was the creation of the UITableViewCell which was wrong. In fact, there are at least two things to check:

1. Consider using autorelease for UITableViewCell:

   ```
   UITableViewCell * cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
   ```
2. Best practice wants you to reuse the `UITableViewCell` instances through the usage of `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier]` (see example below taken from cellForRowAtIndexPath)

   ```
   UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   if (cell == nil)
       cell = [self tableViewCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   ```

The second part, requires you to assign and handle an 'identifier' (a string used to identify the cell).

Please consider posting your code if you still have questions.
Regards,
D.

Comment: Yes it isnt helpful as i have already autorelease the tableview along with tableview cell. Thanks for your reply

Comment: I've been looking the source code of PagedFlowView. Is this one the view which causes memory leak? I see that it uses arrays to keep a strong reference to the UITableViewCells. Have you checked if the cells are correctly removed from the arrays? 
If you can confirm the sample project have the same issue, I'll be debugging it tonight ;)

Comment: Yes if you check this out it really would be helpful, firstly create Entire view with 21 views within it, with high resolution image and tableview including the textview label blabla...you would come to know the leak problem. And yes please make the question up someone might take interest in looking over it

Comment: dna2 check the link i have attached in the question you would find the attached .m file for your reference

Answer (score 0):

Do keep in mind one more thing while working with images. When you are using an image it doesn't take the memory what it shows as file size as many would be expecting (ie., some thing less than 3MB for a 2048 x 1536 ) . Instead it is actually loaded in raw format taking memory based on a calculation as follows:

width x height x n bytes where n is number of bits being taken to represent colors per pixel mostly it is 4.

so for same 2048 x 1536 image it is going to take 12MB.

So now check what is the original resolution of the image you are talking about and calculate how much MB its gonna take, and change your code as per that.

Comment: Yes previously it was somewhat bigger size but i have cropped the images and also reduce the resolution of images. Now the images is in KB and resolution is cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a quick glance at the PagedFlowView proj. Actually I though it was wrongly reusing the UIImageView you were creating, letting the memory increase. But seems to be doing it alright.
I gave a try with an autorelease pool (just on the PagedFlowView using the .tiff files provided) and seems to reduce the amount of allocated bytes of the 20%.

In the PagedFlowView.m file, line 85 you should find the method removeCellAtIndex:(NSInteger)index

Try to edit it this way:

```
- (void)removeCellAtIndex:(NSInteger)index{
  UIView *cell = [_cells objectAtIndex:index];
  if ((NSObject *)cell == [NSNull null]) {
      return;
  }

  @autoreleasepool {

    [self queueReusableCell:cell];

    if (cell.superview) {
        cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
        [cell removeFromSuperview];
    }

    [_cells replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[NSNull null]];
  }
}
```

That should help. But maybe not enough. If you still have the issue I can have a deeper look how PagedFlowView uses _cells and _reusableCells.

Answer (score 0):

Adding 100 empty views also doesn't cause memory problems but adding 10 images starts causing memory problems. Rethink the process of how you are going to present your data.

One way I can suggest is may be reduce the size of thumbnail you are showing in your second view, where you said 1 to 21 views would be there. Then introduce excess step like clicking on that thumbnail to go for detailed screen with original resolution image.

2nd approach, I can think of is having a place holder image. Download only the images of the visible cells asynchronously and writing it to Cache directory, and then keep displaying images of only visible cells

Answer (score 0):

At first - check your dealloc, seems that you are leaking at least music library(and probably a lot more). 
At second - revise your

```
- (UIView *)flowView:(PagedFlowView *)flowView cellForPageAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
```

In your current code:

if view is nil: you are creating autorelease pool but not drain it(and it's better to use @autoreleasepool directive), then you are leaking scrollview(alloc/init, then add subview, but can't see any release), then pointer to image is set to nil, and then you are trying to release it(message to nil is no-op, and the same is for imageview above), etc.this part is full of leaks as it seems from code.

if view is not nil:
You are adding new scrollview etc to this already configured view(and leaking them too). So instead of just reconfiguring these views you are almost recreating them.

I'd suggest you to make subclass of UIView for these views, make a public methods like

```
- (void)configureWithParameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters;
- (id)initWithParameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters;
```

in that class and when flowview asks for view, first try to dequeue reusable cell, if it is nil - alloc/init/autorelease this view with needed params, if view is already created - use  configure method.

Also - this code needs to be heavily refactored. It will be hard to maintain, make changes or improve.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into your code What i found is you are allocating the imageview & webview on cell every time . You can reduce this part by adding the imageview  & webview when cell is nil. As you know cells are reused we can avoid some memory warning for this.

Here is the modified code :

```
static NSString *store=@"cell";
    UITableViewCell *utvc = [[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:store] autorelease];
    if(utvc == nil)
    {
        utvc = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];

UIImageView *textView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 40, 276, 360)];
        textView.tag = 1001;  // some tag value
        [textView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bluelineBg.png"]];
        [utvc addSubview:textView];
        [textview release];

     UIWebView *webv = [[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, -12, 277, 300)];
        webv.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;
        webv.scrollView.scrollEnabled = FALSE;
        webv.tag = 1002;//some tag value
        [webv setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [webv setOpaque:NO];
        [utvc addSubview:webv];
        [webv releae];


    }
  UIImageView *imageview = [cell viewWithTag:1001];

[imageview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bluelineBg.png"]];

UIWebView *webView = [cell viewWithTag:1002];

[webView loadHTMLString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body style='font-family:Helvetica; font-size:14px;background-color: transparent; '><head><style> OL{ color: #555555 } </style></head><br><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Mudra</b> : Prayer Pose<br><br><ol style=\"color:color: #999999;\"><li>Sit comfortably in easy pose with the legs crossed</li><li>Bring the palms together at the center of the chest</li><li>Inhale deeply</li><li>Chant 'Sat Nam' three times or chant the 'Long Time Sunshine' song to finish<br><br><i>Time per repetition : 15 Sec.</i></li></ol></body></html>"] baseURL:Nil];
```